debugging python udf in xlwings
I've recently started having an issue with debugging xlwings UDF functions. I start the debugger in Pycharm set my breakpoints. I can import the functions when not debugging and the functions get called and return values. I then start the debugger in Pycharm and turn on the debug flag in the xlwings ribbon. when I call one of the functions I get "No command specified in the configuration, cannot autostart server". If I then import the functions they execute but the breakpoints in Pycharm are not reached i.e. I cannot enter the debug session in Pycharm. If I then stop the debug session and restart it and then try to debug I get "no command specified in the configuration" and things will only revert back to normal when I turn off the debugger flag, import the functions.
Any ideas why this is happening ?
